# initexmf error -- to increase pdflatex memory

Tags: pdftex, miktex, memory

I am trying to increase main_memory for pdflatex compiler in win7 64.

Using `initexmf` didn't work. This is the error I get:

```
>initexmf --edit-config-file=pdflatex
initexmf: Invalid argument.
initexmf: Data: vi
```

or

```
>initexmf --edit-config-file pdflatex
initexmf: Invalid argument.
initexmf: Data: vi
```

Or which file I can edit directly.
I have tried already to edit (be adding `main_memory=10000000` in the files)

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config\pdflatex.ini
```

and

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\config\pdflatex.ini
```

but it didn't work.

In all cases after compilation I get :

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].
```

any idea ??

PS:

Using pdflatex argument `--main-memory=10000000` seems also is not a solution since I'm using pgfplot externalization the pdflatex command which is invoked by pgfplot does not include `--main-memory=10000000` in the arguments.

lualatex also would not be a solution (it is extremely slow).

Comment: `initexmf --edit-config-file pdflatex` works for me.

Comment: This gets invalid argument error message in my case.

Comment: @A.GH: Trying to edit the files in your main TeX installation is a bad decision BTW, because this will get very probably lost on a future uptdate. The command line works here, too, and this is the only right way to open the correct configuration file. What is your default text editor? The `vi` in the error message is suspect to me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by an error not related to TeX, but the operating system.

Comment: I am not satisfied that this is an error related to the OS.
 My default text editor is notepad.exe. 
even if it was the `vi`, then I would say that still here is the tight place to ask it since it is an error caused by using `initexmf` while the `vi` as a text editor.

Comment: tight place --> right place ;)

Comment: This is a great question, it should never have been closed. The guy has a genuine problem with his LaTeX setup, and this is the LaTeX stackexchange community; saying it's off-topic is perverse. The question is well-written, and other may easily encounter it.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't find a solution for initexmf errors.

Instead I used

```
\tikzset{external/system call= {pdflatex -save-size=80000 
                               -pool-size=10000000 
                               -extra-mem-top=50000000 
                               -extra-mem-bot=10000000 
                               -main-memory=90000000 
                               \tikzexternalcheckshellescape 
                               -halt-on-error 
                               -interaction=batchmode
                               -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
```

to increase the memory used by pdflatex invoked by pgfplots.
This indeed solved my problem.

Comment: This is a workaround to your real issue.